# I am getting an error in node.js service: the string "date" is not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: node.js, service, soap-client, datetime-format

I need help. While passing a datetime parameter to a web service,  i am getting an error: Input XML was not in a correct format.  The value "date" is not a valid AllXsd value. 
I have installed npm date-time and npm dateformat.

Code snippet:

```
Var datetime=require("date-time");
Var dateformat = require("dateformat");

Var dt="#6/2/2017 5:02:03 PM#";
Var d=new date(dt);  //tried with this but getting error 
Var d=new date(dt).toISOString();   //this throws error too but a diff one..input string was not in a correct format
Var d=datetime({local:false}); //also not working
Var d=dateformat(dt, "m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT");  // throws error
Var dtime = [d.getMonth() + 1,
                  d.getDate(),
                  d.getYear()].join('/')];  //this also throws error 

//Service call
service.method(<d>/<dt>, (result) => {
res(result);
```

});

Comment: This is the service in node.js called by angular controller using routes

Comment: The parameter is sqldbtype.datetime in database

Comment: did you find the reason? I'm having the same problem... :(

Answer (score 0):

Use var d = new Date(dt);

Notice the 'D' in Date(dt). You used date(dt).

Comment: It's typo..it's actually Date() i hv used but still getting error

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace here?